# Sending custom HTTP headers via Apache & PHP in a restful webservice

Tags: php, web-services, apache, rest, http-headers

I'm writing a RESTful webservice that returns custom/existing HTTP headers on successful/unsuccessful operations.

For eg., if the authentication fails, the 401 HTTP header will be sent, etc.

I've sent the headers via the PHP header() function, but of course that is not sent back to the caller. What I really need to do is to send headers via Apache, instead of PHP, back to the calling script. I'm carrying out certain checks for the data that I receive in my webservice, and then sending the headers. How would I go about pushing these headers via Apache instead?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the solution. Pass in 'true' as the second argument to header(), and the actual status code as the third argument. For eg., header('HTTP 1.1/400 Bad Request', true, 400). This will force the 400 status code to the caller. I've checked this atleast in LiveHTTPHeaders, so it might work. I'll just need to call this via curl to be completely sure.

Comment: `HTTP 1.1/400 Bad Request` is wrong; it must be `HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request`. And using the second and third parameter when already specifying the response status code in the first parameter is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably do this with PHP and not Apache, but that is just my own preference.  If the call to `header()` isn't working, it's likely because you have whitespace outside of PHP tags somewhere before your call to `header()`.  Take note of this in the [PHP manual](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php):

> Remember that header() must be called
>   before any actual output is sent,
>   either by normal HTML tags, blank
>   lines in a file, or from PHP. It is a
>   very common error to read code with
>   include(), or require(), functions, or
>   another file access function, and have
>   spaces or empty lines that are output
>   before header() is called. The same
>   problem exists when using a single
>   PHP/HTML file.

If you **must** do this with Apache, mod_headers doesn't seem suited.  mod_headers can only set headers based on conditions of whether a request is successful (2xx) or for any request.  See [Header directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_headers.html#header).

Instead, I think it could be done by a combination of using [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html) and [mod_asis](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_asis.html).  I don't have a particular "recipe" for this, but the idea would be to check to see if a request is authorized with mod_rewrite, and if it's not authorized, rewrite/redirect the request URI to an .asis document that contains the header info that you want to send back.

Comment: There are no spaces before the headers call in the script. I've double-checked this. Twice. Any idea how I could use mod_headers to send back the required headers to the caller?

Answer (score 1):

> I've sent the headers via the PHP
>   header() function, but of course that
>   is not sent back to the caller.

What makes you so sure? I'm inclined to think that you're doing something wrong somewhere...

Comment: I called the script via curl, and read the headers. I got 200 OK instead of 500, which I specifically put in there. I also looked it up with the LiveHTTPHeaders add-on and got 200 OK instead of 500.

Comment: Maybe modern browsers are that intelligent, so that they interpret a valid response as 200 OK, instead of 500. But my assumptions is somewhat awkward.